# How can I change a app-engine username/credentials in Maven?

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, maven-3

I worked on app-engine with a google account (entered to maven when doing mvn appengine:update).
I now need to work with a different google account, trying to upload the project give an access error because Maven is caching the user token and my credentials..

How can I switch user?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're on Windows : Go in your "C:/Users/whicheverUserIsYou". You should find a file called ".appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java".

If you're on Linux : the file is in fact "~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java"

This is the file containing your credentials. Delete/Rename it, maven will ask for your credentials again :)

Comment: I'm actually using linux so it was under ~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java

Comment: @AmitBens Thank you for the clarification, I edited this in my answer :)